# getting error when running the application on the fun onLocationResult how to fix it?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    // Define an enum for marker types
    enum class MarkerType(val resourceId: Int, val scale: Float) {
        DEFAULT(-1, 1.0f), // Use -1 to indicate no custom marker
        CUSTOM_1(R.drawable.icon_circle, 0.4f),
        CUSTOM_2(R.drawable.circle_arrow, 0.6f)
    }

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
    private val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private var points: ArrayList<LatLng>? = null
    private var line: Polyline? = null
    private lateinit var rotatingMarker: RotatingMarker
    private lateinit var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private var userLocation: LatLng = LatLng(0.0, 0.0)

    // Location callback defined here
    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
            locationResult?.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                // Handle the new location here
                val newLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                updateMarkerPosition(newLocation)
            }
        }
    }
```

The error/s:

e: file:///D:/Android_Studio_Projects/Live_Route/app/src/main/java/com/example/liveroute/MapsActivity.kt:55:9 Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (onLocationResult(Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult;)V):
fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult): Unit defined in com.example.liveroute.MapsActivity.`<no name provided>`
fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?): Unit defined in com.example.liveroute.MapsActivity.`<no name provided>`

When I'm adding override before the fun like:

```
private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
            locationResult?.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                // Handle the new location here
                val newLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                updateMarkerPosition(newLocation)
            }
        }
    }
```

then I'm getting error on the override:

'onLocationResult' overrides nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "onLocationResult overrides nothing" is caused because you forgot to call `super.onLocationResult()` in your override.

So, depending by your case, add the `super` call.

```
private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
        super.onLocationResult() <--- HERE
        locationResult?.lastLocation?.let { location ->
            // Handle the new location here
            val newLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            updateMarkerPosition(newLocation)
        }
        super.onLocationResult() <--- OR HERE
    }
}
```

Remember to include the `super` call in your overrides.

EDIT

If you don't want to call the super:

From:

```
override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?)
```

To:

```
override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult)
```

Remove the nullable from `LocationResult` in the function arguments (`?` symbol).

Also by doing so, you don't have to call `super.onLocationResult()`.

You can find more information about super and classes from the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#calling-the-superclass-implementation).